# Mac OS not opening driver

Tags: python, macos, selenium, automation

I have saved this route to my echo paths 
`/Users/.../proyect/drivers`

But then when I execute my test I get an error:

`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: unrecognized capability: chromeOptions`

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating selenium using `pip` from the terminal

```
pip install -U selenium
```

And make sure `chromedriver` is accessible from the PATH

EDIT: using `selenium==3.141.0` and updating the package from the IDE, resolved the issue.

Comment: What about using the executable driver file `driver = browser.Chrome('<PATH_to_chromedriver>')` ?

Comment: doesnt work. its only working with this Firefox(executable_path='/Users/.../proyect/drivers/geckodriver'), but i want to open Chrome

Comment: well that makes sense as gecko driver is for firefox, download `chromedriver` from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads, make sure the version of chrome is the in sync with the driver version, and place it in your `drivers` folder and see if that works.

Comment: Lets recap: 
1) selenium is up to date (3.141.0), 
2) executing `chromedriver` directly from the terminal opens the driver. So which python are you using? `python --version`

Comment: selenium is up to date, Python 3.7.3. Executing chromedriver from terminal says Starting ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.106 (f68069574609230cf9b635cd784cfb1bf81bb53a-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#882}) on port 9515 and it doesnt open any driver. export PATH=$PATH:/Users/.../proyect/drivers is added in .bash_profile

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210741/discussion-between-jcaliz-and-fran).

Comment: I had to upgrade selenium in PyCharm>Preferences>Project Interpreter>Selenium